# Why Pandas's 'dropping by condition' doesn't work properly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I like all these 'inplace' methods, and tried to use this to filter particular rows from my time-series dataframe:

```
df.drop(df[(df['location'] == 'City17') | (df['location'] == 'City17 ') | (df['location'] == 'CITY17')].index, inplace=True)
```

But surprisingly it removed way more data and I was left with only one date left. The date was somewhere from the middle of my `DateTime` interval; not the first, nor the last. I've found the solution with the assignment statement like this:

```
df = df[(df['location'] != 'City17') & (df['location'] != 'City17 ') & (df['location'] != 'CITY17')]
```

Now I now that assignments are shorter and work faster than `inplace` methods, but I still wonder why the first `.drop` worked like that.

**Update**
Thanks to hongsy's comment and the best answer from his link, I've solved the issue. The point was in the date column format. It was the `object`, and after I've transformed it to the `DateTime`, my `.drop` method performed correctly.
I still have no clue why it evaluates so, but this is another proof that all `Date` columns should be the `DateTime` type.

Comment: it's very likely that `df` has duplicated index values

Comment: were you able to verify @AndyL. comment is False?

Comment: please see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/6619250)